# Changing from "class" to "React Hooks"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-hooks

My code right now picks a date, and this class is used in another file. Where it renders the date in a ddd D MMMM format. I want to change my code from a class to a react hook, and I'm not very sure how to do this. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
 
class DayPicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: Date() };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: Date(),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.dayPicker}>
        {moment()
          .add(daysToAdd ? daysToAdd : 0, "day")
          .format("ddd D MMMM")}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DayPicker;
```

If someone manages to convert my code into react hooks, please explain the process to me as it would be a great change to learn more about react Hooks.

Comment: I have managed to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep in mind the following things which converting the classes to functional components with hooks.

First: use `useState` hook in place of state.

Second: change lifecycle methods to `useEffect` hooks.

Third: Change classes variables to `useRef`.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import moment from "moment";

const DayPicker = ()=> {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  const timerID = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
     timerID.current = setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);

     return () => {
        // This function will execute on unmount
        clearInterval(timerID.current);
     }
  }, []) // empty array here signifies that the effect will be run once on initial mount


  const tick = () => {
    setDate(new Date())
  }

    return (
      <div className={style.dayPicker}>
        {moment()
          .add(daysToAdd ? daysToAdd : 0, "day")
          .format("ddd D MMMM")}
      </div>
    );
}

export default DayPicker;
```

For a detailed understanding of each of these hooks, read the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Comment: in this you could also take out the function `tick()` and just call `setDate(new Date())` by itself in setInterval

Comment: @BradBall, yes we could do that as well, but I didn't want to confuse the OP